# Pumping Lemma proofs

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

I am having a hard time writing a Pumping Lemma contradictory proof for the below statements.

1) $L_1 = \{ ww \mid w \in E^* \}$ <--- I don't understand how to read this. This is what I tried: For any string (of any length) that can be cut down the middle there exists and element of any length? so I would have to pick a string of length X that when I split the string in half, it still can be any length? this is really confusing to try to prove, i'd appreciate any suggestions with this one.

2) $L_2 = \{ a^{2^n} \mid n \geq 0 \}$ <---- same with this, I don't understand what kind of string I would have to pick to disprove this.

**Note:** That is a Pumping Lemma is for Regular Languages.

I'd appreciate any hints or comments that may help me disprove these.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I've tried to TeXify your post, please check if it is alright.

Comment: Are you talking about pumping lemma for regular or context free languages?

Comment: Regular languages. Thanks.

Comment: accepted! thanks for all the help! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (1) the language is repeated strings from some alphabet. If $E$ was $\{0,1\}$ then $E^*$ is all binary strings and the language is $\{,00,11,0000,0101,1010,1111,000000,001001,\ldots\}$. It suffices to prove this language is not regular for $E=\{0,1\}$ since intersections of regular languages are regular. Now suppose the machine that recognizes it has $n$ states and consider the double of a binary string of length $n$: you must be able to pump one half of it and not the other.. so pick the string of length $n$ that looks like `1000`[n zeros]`001`, but doing that breaks the property that it it is a double.

For (2) the language is $\{a,aa,aaaa,aaaaaaaa,aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,\ldots\}$.

Suppose it was recognized by a machine of $n$ states, consider the smallest $i$ such that $n \le 2^i$. In matching the string $a^{2^i}$ some substring must pump. Suppose that substring had length $k \le 2^i$. Then the machine must also match $a^{2^{i} + k}$ and $a^{2^{i} + k + k}$ one of which is not a power of two.

Comment: @MHZ, take 1000110001 and pump the left half, e.g. 1000000000110001

Comment: @MHZ, the $ww$ means that the two halves are the same.

Comment: @MHZ, but I didn't so there's no issue.

Comment: @Karolis Juodele please explain your comment....

Comment: @user58512, sorry, I now see that my comment was wrong. I confused the condition that $|xy| < p$ with one that $|y| <p$. I'll erase it...

Comment: Can you please explain again why your argument works for (1) in simpler terms? sorry, this is new to me and I am trying to learn the strategy to tackle these kinds of problems...

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė, it's my fault for not explaining clearly, thank you for your reply!

Comment: @MHZ, We assume the machine has some finite number $n$ states. We reason that strings longer than $n$ must contain a substring that can pump (be repeated indefinitely). I decided to pick a string of length $2n$ so that we could pump the first half of it! That means if we use a string like `10[00]0011000001` which is in the language (using brackets to denote the part which can be pumped) then so is `10[00][00]0011000001`.. but that gives a contradiction since it's not a doubled string. The contradiction disproves that the language is regular.

Comment: OK! that makes sense! thanks for the reply!

Comment: Can you please explain your proof (2) more simply? how come we are disproving this language by finding an 'a' that does not have a power of two? pretty much any 'n' value you plug in other than 1 will disprove this?

Comment: @MHZ, pumping lemma says that, if you take a long enough word in a regular language, there will be some short enough substring in it, that you can repeat any number of times and still get only words in the language. He picked some large word of length $2^n$ and a substring in it of length $k$. Because $2^n+ik$ can't always be a power of $2$, the above condition doesn't hold.

Answer (score 0):

MHZ, maybe the url, http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~sanjay/cs4232/t4ans.pdf, will help you with some idea. See question 1, through (a) to (d). After reading it, maybe you konw how to prove it. :-)